# my trained model gives me wrong predict on input images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm making a program for arabic characters recognition using CNN on keras, and then i've trained the model trying different architectures eventhought the one proposed by the creators of the datasets. the problem is when i predict on test_data included with datasets good results, however when I'm trying to predict with actual image that I input or the one generated by canvas (im making webapp) it gives me all the time wrong predictions no matter the number of images I've tried.

I've saved and loaded the model with good accuracy and less loss, and I've uploaded the images using the openCV lib and doing reshape so it can fit to the model and make it grayscale, after that I transform it to an array and feed it to the predict function, the output are wrong, in comparation I've loaded test_data with labels and feed it to model gives me true results

so this is my code from loading datasets to train to test_data results to images_input wrong results

```
# Training letters images and labels files
letters_training_images_file_path = "drive/My Drive/ARlearning/Arabic Handwritten Characters Dataset CSV/training images.zip"
letters_training_labels_file_path = "drive/My Drive/ARlearning/Arabic Handwritten Characters Dataset CSV/training labels.zip"
# Testing letters images and labels files
letters_testing_images_file_path = "drive/My Drive/ARlearning/Arabic Handwritten Characters Dataset CSV/testing images.zip"
letters_testing_labels_file_path = "drive/My Drive/ARlearning/Arabic Handwritten Characters Dataset CSV/testing labels.zip"

# Loading dataset into dataframes
training_letters_images = pd.read_csv(letters_training_images_file_path, compression='zip', header=None)
training_letters_labels = pd.read_csv(letters_training_labels_file_path, compression='zip', header=None)
testing_letters_images = pd.read_csv(letters_testing_images_file_path, compression='zip', header=None)
testing_letters_labels = pd.read_csv(letters_testing_labels_file_path, compression='zip', header=None)


# Training digits images and labels files
digits_training_images_file_path = "drive/My Drive/ARlearning/Arabic Handwritten Digits Dataset CSV/training images.zip"
digits_training_labels_file_path = "drive/My Drive/ARlearning/Arabic Handwritten Digits Dataset CSV/training labels.zip"
# Testing digits images and labels files
digits_testing_images_file_path = "drive/My Drive/ARlearning/Arabic Handwritten Digits Dataset CSV/testing images.zip"
digits_testing_labels_file_path = "drive/My Drive/ARlearning/Arabic Handwritten Digits Dataset CSV/testing labels.zip"

# Loading dataset into dataframes
training_digits_images = pd.read_csv(digits_training_images_file_path, compression='zip', header=None)
training_digits_labels = pd.read_csv(digits_training_labels_file_path, compression='zip', header=None)
testing_digits_images = pd.read_csv(digits_testing_images_file_path, compression='zip', header=None)
testing_digits_labels = pd.read_csv(digits_testing_labels_file_path, compression='zip', header=None)

training_digits_images_scaled = training_digits_images.values.astype('float32')/255
training_digits_labels = training_digits_labels.values.astype('int32')
testing_digits_images_scaled = testing_digits_images.values.astype('float32')/255
testing_digits_labels = testing_digits_labels.values.astype('int32')

training_letters_images_scaled = training_letters_images.values.astype('float32')/255
training_letters_labels = training_letters_labels.values.astype('int32')
testing_letters_images_scaled = testing_letters_images.values.astype('float32')/255
testing_letters_labels = testing_letters_labels.values.astype('int32')

print("Training images of digits after scaling")
print(training_digits_images_scaled.shape)
training_digits_images_scaled[0:5]

print("Training images of letters after scaling")
print(training_letters_images_scaled.shape)
training_letters_images_scaled[0:5]

# one hot encoding
# number of classes = 10 (digits classes) + 28 (arabic alphabet classes)
number_of_classes = 38
training_letters_labels_encoded = to_categorical(training_letters_labels, num_classes=number_of_classes)
testing_letters_labels_encoded = to_categorical(testing_letters_labels, num_classes=number_of_classes)
training_digits_labels_encoded = to_categorical(training_digits_labels, num_classes=number_of_classes)
testing_digits_labels_encoded = to_categorical(testing_digits_labels, num_classes=number_of_classes)


# reshape input digit images to 64x64x1
training_digits_images_scaled = training_digits_images_scaled.reshape([-1, 64, 64, 1])
testing_digits_images_scaled = testing_digits_images_scaled.reshape([-1, 64, 64, 1])

# reshape input letter images to 64x64x1
training_letters_images_scaled = training_letters_images_scaled.reshape([-1, 64, 64, 1])
testing_letters_images_scaled = testing_letters_images_scaled.reshape([-1, 64, 64, 1])

print(training_digits_images_scaled.shape, training_digits_labels_encoded.shape, testing_digits_images_scaled.shape, testing_digits_labels_encoded.shape)
print(training_letters_images_scaled.shape, training_letters_labels_encoded.shape, testing_letters_images_scaled.shape, testing_letters_labels_encoded.shape)

training_data_images = np.concatenate((training_digits_images_scaled, training_letters_images_scaled), axis=0) 
training_data_labels = np.concatenate((training_digits_labels_encoded, training_letters_labels_encoded), axis=0)
print("Total Training images are {} images of shape".format(training_data_images.shape[0]))
print(training_data_images.shape, training_data_labels.shape)


testing_data_images = np.concatenate((testing_digits_images_scaled, testing_letters_images_scaled), axis=0) 
testing_data_labels = np.concatenate((testing_digits_labels_encoded, testing_letters_labels_encoded), axis=0)
print("Total Testing images are {} images of shape".format(testing_data_images.shape[0]))
print(testing_data_images.shape, testing_data_labels.shape)

def create_model(optimizer='adam', kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu'):
  # create model
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, padding='same', input_shape=(64, 64, 1), kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, activation=activation))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))

  model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, activation=activation))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))

  model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding='same', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, activation=activation))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))

  model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding='same', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, activation=activation))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())



  #Fully connected final layer
  model.add(Dense(38, activation='softmax'))

  # Compile model
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=optimizer)
  return model

model = create_model()
model.summary()

model = create_model(optimizer='Adam', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')


epochs = 20
batch_size = 20

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='weights.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

history = model.fit(training_data_images, training_data_labels, 
                    validation_data=(testing_data_images, testing_data_labels),
                    epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

the training results :

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
Train on 73440 samples, validate on 13360 samples
Epoch 1/10
73440/73440 [==============================] - 52s 702us/step - loss: 0.3535 - acc: 0.9062 - val_loss: 0.2023 - val_acc: 0.9236

Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.20232, saving model to weights.hdf5
Epoch 2/10
73440/73440 [==============================] - 48s 658us/step - loss: 0.1068 - acc: 0.9672 - val_loss: 0.1701 - val_acc: 0.9469

Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 0.20232 to 0.17013, saving model to weights.hdf5
Epoch 3/10
73440/73440 [==============================] - 49s 667us/step - loss: 0.0799 - acc: 0.9753 - val_loss: 0.1112 - val_acc: 0.9707

Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 0.17013 to 0.11123, saving model to weights.hdf5
Epoch 4/10
73440/73440 [==============================] - 47s 638us/step - loss: 0.0684 - acc: 0.9786 - val_loss: 0.0715 - val_acc: 0.9800

Epoch 00004: val_loss improved from 0.11123 to 0.07150, saving model to weights.hdf5
Epoch 5/10
73440/73440 [==============================] - 48s 660us/step - loss: 0.0601 - acc: 0.9812 - val_loss: 0.2134 - val_acc: 0.9343

Epoch 00005: val_loss did not improve from 0.07150
Epoch 6/10
73440/73440 [==============================] - 47s 647us/step - loss: 0.0545 - acc: 0.9828 - val_loss: 0.0641 - val_acc: 0.9814

Epoch 00006: val_loss improved from 0.07150 to 0.06413, saving model to weights.hdf5
Epoch 7/10
73440/73440 [==============================] - 48s 655us/step - loss: 0.0490 - acc: 0.9846 - val_loss: 0.8639 - val_acc: 0.7332

Epoch 00007: val_loss did not improve from 0.06413
Epoch 8/10
73440/73440 [==============================] - 48s 660us/step - loss: 0.0472 - acc: 0.9854 - val_loss: 0.0509 - val_acc: 0.9844

Epoch 00008: val_loss improved from 0.06413 to 0.05093, saving model to weights.hdf5
Epoch 9/10
73440/73440 [==============================] - 47s 644us/step - loss: 0.0433 - acc: 0.9859 - val_loss: 0.0713 - val_acc: 0.9791

Epoch 00009: val_loss did not improve from 0.05093
Epoch 10/10
73440/73440 [==============================] - 49s 665us/step - loss: 0.0434 - acc: 0.9861 - val_loss: 0.2861 - val_acc: 0.9012

Epoch 00010: val_loss did not improve from 0.05093
```

and after evaluating the model with test_data

Test Accuracy: 0.9843562874251497

Test Loss: 0.05093173268935584

and now trying to predict classes from test_data

```
def get_predicted_classes(model, data, labels=None):
  image_predictions = model.predict(data)
  predicted_classes = np.argmax(image_predictions, axis=1)
  true_classes = np.argmax(labels, axis=1)
  return predicted_classes, true_classes

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

def get_classification_report(y_true, y_pred):
  print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))

y_pred, y_true = get_predicted_classes(model, testing_data_images, testing_data_labels)
get_classification_report(y_true, y_pred)

    precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.98      0.99      0.99      1000
           1       0.99      0.99      0.99      1000
           2       0.98      1.00      0.99      1000
           3       1.00      0.99      0.99      1000
           4       1.00      0.99      0.99      1000
           5       0.99      0.98      0.99      1000
           6       0.99      0.99      0.99      1000
           7       1.00      0.99      1.00      1000
           8       1.00      0.99      1.00      1000
           9       1.00      0.99      0.99      1000
          10       0.99      1.00      1.00       120
          11       1.00      0.97      0.99       120
          12       0.87      0.97      0.91       120
          13       1.00      0.89      0.94       120
          14       0.98      0.99      0.98       120
          15       0.96      0.98      0.97       120
          16       0.99      0.97      0.98       120
          17       0.91      0.99      0.95       120
          18       0.94      0.91      0.92       120
          19       0.94      0.93      0.93       120
          20       0.96      0.90      0.93       120
          21       0.99      0.93      0.96       120
          22       0.99      1.00      1.00       120
          23       0.91      0.99      0.95       120
          24       0.99      0.96      0.97       120
          25       0.96      0.96      0.96       120
          26       0.95      0.96      0.95       120
          27       0.99      0.97      0.98       120
          28       0.99      0.99      0.99       120
          29       0.95      0.84      0.89       120
          30       0.84      0.97      0.90       120
          31       0.98      0.98      0.98       120
          32       0.98      1.00      0.99       120
          33       0.99      1.00      1.00       120
          34       0.96      0.90      0.93       120
          35       0.99      0.96      0.97       120
          36       0.95      0.97      0.96       120
          37       0.98      0.99      0.99       120

   micro avg       0.98      0.98      0.98     13360
   macro avg       0.97      0.97      0.97     13360
weighted avg       0.98      0.98      0.98     13360
```

and for the prediction with input_image

```
    x = imread('output.png', mode='L')
    x = np.invert(x)
    x = imresize(x, (64, 64))
    #x = x/255
    x = x.reshape((-1,64,64,1))

    with graphAR.as_default():
        out = modelAR.predict(x)
        #print(out)
        print(np.argmax(out, axis=1))
        response = np.array_str(np.argmax(out, axis=1))
        print(response)
```

but the results always false (wrong)

I expect true outputs for input_images for example

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmBhg.jpg

expected predict : alif-أ

results : [[0]] = sifr-0

some images_inputs ive tried

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozElj.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkK0q.jpg

https://imgur.com/6axcUdp

https://imgur.com/8jQ73bX

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjIVQ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In the training phase, you are using these functions before you train. Scaling and conversion to integer by the looks of it.

```
training_digits_images_scaled = training_digits_images.values.astype('float32')/255
training_digits_labels = training_digits_labels.values.astype('int32')
```

During prediction, you have to carry out the same exact functions. In the prediction for input_image,

```
#Convert to grayscale only if training images are in grayscale too.
#It's generally a good idea to train and predict with grayscaled images.

x = imread('output.png', mode='L')
# Not sure why you are doing this
#x = np.invert(x) 
x = x.astype('float')/255
x = x.astype('int')
x = x.reshape((-1,64,64,1))

## Continue with prediction function
```

This should work. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: thanks for answering, i did what u told me, the predection for all the characters : [0] also, im not sure why you told me to do x = x.astype('float')/255 x = x.astype('int') cause if you notice not been used on the same file type float for the images and int for labels